# What is the dimension of V?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let B an $n\times n$ noninvertible matrix. Let V be the set of all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ such that $BA=0$. What is the dimension of $B$?

(the following is my process:)

to simplify the question, I set $V=\{A\mid BA=0,B \text{ is }n\times n \text{ noninvertible matrix}\}$

then I try some cases like:
[image]
hence the dimension of V is 2.

---

then, I have no idea how to move on to $n\times n$. I also have no idea why the question emphasize $B$ is an noninvertible matrix.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Most likely, they emphasize that $B$ is non-invertible because the case where $B$ is invertible is boring, as $A = 0$ would be the only element of $V$ Also, you say both "dimension of $B$" and "dimension of $A$" where I think you mean "dimension of $V$".

Comment: @Arthur got it thanks and yes I mean the dimension of V.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ denote the columns of $A$.  We can write
$$
BA = B \pmatrix{a_1 & \cdots & a_n} = \pmatrix{Ba_1 & \cdots & Ba_n}.
$$
So, we have $BA = 0$ if and only if every column of $A$ is a solution to $Bx = 0$.